# Simple Regular Expression on HTML Tags

Tags: php, regex

***Problem One:***

```
</a>              

19-10-2011, 04:49 PM

             </td> <td class="thread"
```

**How to fetch the DATE and TIME i.e. 19-10-2011, 04:49 PM**

**Note:** the above snippet could have unstable spacing as you see above e.g. `</td> <td class`

**My attempt:**

`preg_match("#</a>(.*?)</td> <td class=\"thread\"#", $page, $fetchContent);`

**Result:** empty

---

***Problem Two:***

```
<div id="post_message_43345">ANY TYPE OF CONTENT INCLUDING SPACES</tr> <tr>
```

**I need to fetch "ANY TYPE OF CONTENT".**

**Note:** the spacing between tags such as `</tr> <tr>` could vary from page to another.

**My attempt:**

```
preg_match("#<div id=\"post_message_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\">(.*?)</tr> <tr>#", $page, $fetchedContent);
```

**Result:** empty

*I'm looking for rough temporary short snippet for one task. Therefore, i didn't use HTML parser.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

You need to use the `s` flag to have `.` match newline characters too:

```
preg_match("#</a>(.*?)</td> <td class=\"thread\"#s", $page, $fetchContent);
```

You'd probably be better off matching the date directly though:

```
preg_match("#([0123]?[0-9]-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:[0-9]{4})),? ?((?:0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9] ?[AP]M)#",...)
```

**edit** - this date regex will be a little faster (added boundaries either side):

```
preg_match("#\\b([0123]?[0-9]-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:[0-9]{4}))[, ]{1,3}((?:0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9] ?[AP]M)\\b#",...)
```

For both, the date is in `$results[1]` and the time is in `$results[2]`.

### Problem 2

Again the `s` flag, and to have varying spaces between the `</tr> <tr>` use `*`.

```
preg_match("#<div id=\"post_message_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\">(.*?)</tr> *<tr>#s", $page, $fetchedContent);
```

If you want to allow for newlines between the `</tr>` and `<tr>` then do `\s*` instead. Same for Problem 1.

Comment: I'm about to pick your answer. Date is fetched but time isn't fetched. Any idea? I tried to solve, i couldn't...

Comment: With the second regex? That captures the date in the first capturing group and time in the second ... http://regexr.com?2vpbi or [preg_match tester](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=%23%28%5B0123%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D-%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D%29-%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%29%29%2C%3F+%3F%28%28%3F%3A0%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D%29%3A%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D+%3F%5BAP%5DM%29%23&subject=%3C%2Fa%3E++++++++++++++%0D%0A%0D%0A19-10-2011%2C+04%3A49+PM%0D%0A%0D%0A+++++++++++++%3C%2Ftd%3E+%3Ctd+class%3D%22thread%22+)

Comment: Yes, ("#([0123]?[0-9]-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:[0-9]{4})),? ?((?:0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9] ?[AP]M)#",...)

Comment: Weird...It didn't work with me...Anyhow, thanks for the resources, will check it out later.

Comment: Worked...I picked element 1 in the array when i supposed to pick elelment 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: the above snippet could have unstable spacing as you see above

You want it to match newlines also. The `.` doesn't do that normally. This would require the `#s` modifier basically:

```
  preg_match('#</a>(.*?)</td> <td class="thread"#s', ...
```

But you could also just add `\s*` twice around your `(.*?)` capture group. Also between the `</td>` and `<td`.

And then you could make your regex more specific `\d\d-\d\d-\d\d, \d\d:\d\d` to only capture the date. That might make matching the tags somewhat redundant.

> Note: the spacing between tags such as   could vary from page to another.

You can again just use `\s*` which matches spaces and newlines in any combination.